# Power BI Embedded deleteVisual usage in a layout file

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I am trying to use the `await page.deleteVisual("8d0e01e7a860c2e5706d");` command when I layout a report page. This seems logical to me. I am going to place various visuals on the page for a certain group of people.  For another group of people I will delete a few other visuals and keep this one.  I get the following error:

> TypeError: report.deleteVisual is not a function at changeLayout (PQLayout.js:56)

Most of the documentation pages are bare and lacking good examples, but this page doesn't help much for the error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/remove-visual

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

deleteVisual is a method provided by the Page object but from the error it seems you are calling it for the report object. You should use `page.deleteVisual("VISUAL_GUID")` to delete the visual.

deleteVisual is a method of [powerbi-report-authoring SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-report-authoring).

You can refer to the live showcase to understand the usage of this SDK:

1. Live showcase: [Quickly create and personalize visuals](https://playground.powerbi.com/showcases-gallery/quick-visual-creator)
2. Showcase's source code: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Embedded-Showcases/tree/main/Quickly%20create%20and%20personalize%20visuals

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/remove-visual

Comment: The page object did not work either. It appears deleteVisual is only available for visuals that you create in report authoring which makes little sense to me. If I can delete pages and move visuals around, why can't I delete them?

Comment: Once you import 'powerbi-report-authoring', you can delete any visual on any page using page.deleteVisual(<visual name>)

Please refer authoring API from the following link:
https://playground.powerbi.com/dev-sandbox

Comment: They also need to be visible which defeats the purpose.